# How to gracefully stop a rethinkdb server running in the background in linux?

Tags: rethinkdb

How to stop a rethinkdb server in linux? Is there a command to gracefully shut down a rehinkdb instance? I haven't found anything about in the docs. So if I start a rethinkdb instance in foreground from the
commandline, rethinkdb handles the SIGINT sent from the keyboard. But I'm not sure if rethinkdb gracefully handles the SIGTERM signal sent by the kill command when rethinkdb is running in background.So what is the right way to shut down rethinkdb when is running as a background process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
kill -INT pid
```

(where pid is the id of the rethinkdb process)

This is what the init.d script uses.  It allows you to set it up to start at server start, and use standard linux init.d commands, like

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rethinkdb restart
```

This page talks about configuring rethinkdb on server start: https://rethinkdb.com/docs/start-on-startup/

This is the source of the init.d script linked to from the above page.
https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/next/packaging/assets/init/rethinkdb

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the init.d startup outlined [here](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/start-on-startup/),

`sudo /etc/init.d/rethinkdb stop`

and then

`sudo /etc/init.d/rethinkdb restart`

to resume.